# calling jquery functions

Tags: jquery

How can i call a jquery function onload and later onClick?
I dont think its hard, but i cant find the anwser anywhere...
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to run some code twice, then wrap it into a named function and then call that function whenever you need.

```
function MyCodeToRun(){
   // Put the code you want to run here
}

// Call it on load
$(function(){
   MyCodeToRun();
   // You can do other stuff on load here as well
});

// Call it on click
$("#yourselector").click(function(){
   MyCodeToRun();
   // You can do other stuff on click here as well
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
function myFunction(){/*do something*/}
```

and then add event handlers

```
$("mySelector").click(myFunction);
$("mySelector").load(myFunction);
```

hope this helps

Comment: um, ok i get it that my "blabla"(edited now) wasn't funny.. but why the downvote ? (actually intrigued)

Comment: I didn't (and don't) downvote, but I imagine the "blablabla" combined with incorrect information (`onclick` and `onload` instead of `click` and `load`) was the reason.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info.. when i had a second look at my code and i noticed that i was using the wrong event handlers..